# Trying to toggle Bootstrap Button text onclick with jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navigation

I have a mobile nav and would like to alternate the text of the bootstrap collapse button. If Menu is clicked, change to X. If X is clicked, change to Menu.  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whataboon/36dqww0q/16/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function () {
        if (matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
        var menu_text = $('.navbar-toggle').text();
            if(menu_text == 'X' ){
                $('.navbar-toggle').text("Menu");
            }
            elseif (menu_text == 'Menu'){
                $('.navbar-toggle').text("X");
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why is not working the way you want, is because it's taking all text inside that button. This means that it takes "Toggle Navigation MENU". You'd have to get rid of that, and also, Trim the ext so that the comparison would work like expected. Something else to take into account is that Caps letters are NOT the same as lowercase letters. 'Menu' and "MENU" are not the same to a computer.

Here's the fixed code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function () {
        if (matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
           // alert('ENTERED');
            var temptxt = $('.navbar-toggle span').text().trim();
            $('.navbar-toggle span').text('');

        var menu_text = $('.navbar-toggle').text().trim();

            //alert(menu_text);
            if(menu_text == 'X' ){

                $('.navbar-toggle').text("MENU");
            }
            else if (menu_text == 'MENU'){

                $('.navbar-toggle').text("X");
            }
        }
       $('.navbar-toggle span').text(temptxt); 

    });
});
```

Oh! And I forgot to mention, the console gave me an error because of **elseif** so I just separated into **else if** which works like a charm.

Comment: don't I fill silly...works like a charm. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: remember to mark the question as answered if it was.